# Python type hinting for class factories

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance

Consider the following code:

```py
class A(): pass

class B(A): 
    def bar(self): pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)

def C(cls: type[T]):
    class _C:
        def __init__(self): 
            self.foo = cls()
    return _C
    
D = C(B)
D().foo.bar
```

Pylance infers the type of `D().foo` as just `T`, and hence complains that `bar` doesn't exist. What can I do to have `D` carry the information that every instance of `D` uses `B`?

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I noticed that when I write the following, Pylance correctly infers that `D().foo` is of type `B`, but still complains because it we assign `cls()` of type `T` to a variable of type `S`.

```py
def C(cls: type[T]):
    class _C(Generic[S]):
        def __init__(self): 
            self.foo: S = cls()
    return _C[cls]
```

(Disclaimer: A previous version of this question was posed inaccurately and closed.)